# stuck at laravel, trying to save data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save data but get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save(): Argument #1 ($model) must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in C:\xampp\laravelprojects\testfrihand\app\Http\Controllers\ProfileController.php on line 52

This is the function that will save the data:

```
public function updateprofile(Request $request, Profile $about){
       auth()->user()->profile()->save([
        
            'about'=>$request->about,
            
        ]);
```

user model:

```
public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Profile::class);
    }
```

I'm not sure whether the error is in the model. I assume it is because it is mentioning relations. But I'm at loss here, since if I change to create it works fine for some reason

Comment: Welcome to SO ... if you want to 'create' a new record via the relationship and pass attributes you are looking for the `create` method, not `save` ... if you are trying to update this related record you could use `update` but it depends if you want to use eloquent or bypass it to do the update

Comment: But I don't want to create. It's for a user profile, so he will insert data that can then only be updated, not created again

Comment: update only worked if I had data created. As far as I've understood it, I need to use save

Comment: if you don't have a record created then you are not 'updating' you are creating

Comment: I need to create, but the user cannot create many abouts. I'm bad at english, I'm trying my best to explain. If you log into your account, you have an about field. You write about yourself and this will be sent to the database, if he write in the same field, it will be updated not created again

Comment: If I use create, I send in many abouts and that's not what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can use updateOrCreate to create if not exists and / or update if exists,

```
auth()->user()->profile()->updateOrCreate(['user_id'=>auth()->id()],[
    
        'about'=>$request->about,
        
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks man! It worked. I was stuck on this for the entire day. By the way, what is the difference between updateOrCreate and using save?

Comment: @CarlMenger save() method acts like INSERT when you give it new model instance i.e. ->save(new Profile(['key'=>'value])) and it can also acts like UPDATE when you give it existing model instance and change some props. updateOrCreate is a short hand way of checking for both things at once

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just saw that it both inserted and updated and asumed it was the right method to use. Googled for hours it's wierd I never came across updateOrCreate

Answer (score 1):

If at this point in your code you can guarantee that this user has a related profile record you can retrieve that Profile via the relationship and update it:

```
auth()->user()->profile->update([...]);
```

If its possible the user doesn't have a profile already you can use something like `updateOrCreate`:

```
auth()->user()->profile()->updateOrCreate(
    [],
    ['about' => $request->about]
);
```

Which is basically this:

```
auth()->user()->profile()->firstOrNew()->fill([...])->save();
```

Comment: updateOrCreate worked, thanks man! By the way what is the difference between save and the updateorcreate?

Comment: calling `save` on a relationship is expecting the related model instance to be passed, so to call `$user->profile()->save()` would require you passing a `Profile` model to it ... `updateOrCreate` is doing a select query against the relationship to find a matching record, if it is found it fills it and saves it (update), if it doesn't find it it creates one using those attributes  ... calling `save` on a relationship is different than calling `save` on a model

Comment: You make null the first attribute `[]`, which is a conditional attribute (probably it is user_id). how the first condition worked here without a given value?

Comment: @sta there are no attributes to search for in this example, the relationship itself adds the conditions needed to make sure this record belongs to its parent, so this is basically saying get me the first related record, as passing an empty array to `where` adds no where conditions

Comment: @sta that is this:  `auth()->user()->profile()->firstOrNew()->fill([...])->save()` basically ... good question btw

Comment: @lagbox Nice explanation,  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that , save method accept  object not array and you try to send array to it , so you can do like this :-

```
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->about = $request->about;
auth()->user()->profile()->save($profile);
```

or you can use update method like this :-

```
auth()->user()->profile()->update([
        
            'about'=>$request->about,
            
        ]);
```

Comment: The first answer gave me this: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\laravelprojects\testfrihand\app\Http\Controllers\ProfileController.php on line 52 and exactly 1 expected. And I don't want to update, because then I need a record already there

Comment: try this ,
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->about = $request->about;
auth()->user()->profile()->save($profile); 

in the second solution you can use firstOrNew()->fill()->save() instead of update 
and tell me the result